# How do I get Jetty to accept incoming client connections over HTTPS from any remote machine?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a Jetty server running with the SslSocketConnector to enable https connections from clients. I have a self-signed key (CN="localhost) as the only key in my java keystore file, and this is set as the keystore on the SslContextFactory constructor and also on that context's trustStore property.

This allows connections happily from clients over https on the same machine, i.e. localhost, but naturally not from any remote machines. I could add a certificate to the truststore for every remote client that will need to connect, but I don't want to do that. I want Jetty to actually allow connections over https from **any** remote client machine.

Is this possible?

btw. I am using Jetty 8.1 on Java JDK 7

Here is my code:

```
// setup jetty server SSL context
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new     SslContextFactory(this.queenKeystorePath);
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(this.queenKeystorePassword);
sslContextFactory.setTrustStore(trustKeystorePath);
sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword(trustKeystorePassword);
sslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(false);

// create a https connector
SslSocketConnector connector = new SslSocketConnector(sslContextFactory);
connector.setPort(httpsPort);

// register the SSL connector
server.addConnector(connector);

ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", true, false);
```

Comment: `SslSocketConnector` is from an old version of Jetty, so old in fact that I can say with 100% confidence that your version is EOL (End of Life) now.  It is not advisable to be using SSL with EOL servers or clients, that is a security risk (this statement applies to all servers and clients, not just Jetty)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Joakim. The problem is that I am kind of restricted to Jetty 8.1, because a whole bunch of our software depends on that version.